# Flex : Soap Response cannot be decoded, Decoding Error

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

**[RPC Fault faultString="SOAP Response cannot be decoded. Raw response: " faultCode="DecodingError" faultDetail="null"]**

I get this error in flex 3.2 compiled application.

1. this error is caught by webservice fault handler.
2. this error could not caught by try{} - catch{} block which is in .net webservices also
3. Finally the iis error log has been referred, the following error has been logged
   in log file

05:36:12 192.168.2.198 POST /localhost/Test/sampleTest.asmx 500
05:36:12 192.168.2.198 POST /localhost/Test/sampleTest.asmx 500
05:36:12 192.168.2.198 POST /localhost/Test/sampleTest.asmx 500

in some times the error message as follows

05:35:30 192.168.2.198 POST /localhost/Test/sampleTest.asmx  200
05:35:38 127.0.0.1 GET /localhost/Test/sampleTest.asmx  403

->. The reply contails the error code 403 or 500 and the response is empty.

```
if anybody knows the solution please help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of reasons for this problem.

1. If you used the WSDL Wizard, be sure that you refreshed your WebService. (Update and later refresh button)
2. The WebService, does it compile?.
3. If you are returning objects in the WebService,  are they correctly serialized?

If you cannot debug your webservice in the try catch, i believe that is the first point. It is not well imported

Tell me if it worked.

Greetings.

Comment: i am getting the same error ... i have debugged the code .. i am getting the output at web service i have made but i am not able to fetch them in flex datagrid.

Comment: what do you mean by not able to fetch it? are you getting the same error?

Comment: now it is solved . earlier my data Grid was empty after the completion of the function . now I have bind my web service directly to the Datagrid 
This Link http://nishadmusthafa.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/consuming-a-net-based-web-service-from-a-flex-application-using-the-data-centric-development-dcd-in-flash-builder-4/ helped me